# When backuping MBR, is there a differece between dd with count = 2 and count = 1 with corresponding blocksize?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

For instance, I'm going to backup MBR from /dev/sda hdd. 
I can do this in two ways:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=~/mbr.bak bs=512 count=1
dd if=/dev/sda of=~/mbr.bak bs=256 count=2
```

Will I get different backups? Or it is just a matter of speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying it yourself and checking the results?

```
# dd if=/dev/sda of=~/mbr.bak bs=512 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.00229764 s, 223 kB/s

# dd if=/dev/sda of=~/mbr.bak2 bs=256 count=2
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.00235596 s, 217 kB/s
```

Let's compare the results of the two commands, shall we?

```
# cmp mbr.bak mbr.bak2
#
```

No differences, just as expected.